# Get `Meta` attribute `content` by selecting `property` attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags

In jQuery you can do this:

```
$("meta[property='fb:app_id']").attr("content");
```

Which will give you the `content` attribute value from the `meta`-tag with `property` attribute "fb:app_id".

How can I do this in plain ol' Javascript?

Thank you in advance. :-)

Kenneth

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('meta[property~="fb:app_id"][content]').content
```

Answer (score 15):

Not as elegant as JQuery I'm afraid...

```
var metaTags=document.getElementsByTagName("meta");

var fbAppIdContent = "";
for (var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
    if (metaTags[i].getAttribute("property") == "fb:app_id") {
        fbAppIdContent = metaTags[i].getAttribute("content");
        break;
    }
}

console.log(fbAppIdContent);
```

Comment: Not quite the same, you'll need to `break` on the first occurrance of `fb:app_id`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: True. I have edited the JS to be the direct equivalent of the JQuery statement.

Comment: In ES6 it is slightly better: `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('meta')).find($meta => {
          return $meta.getAttribute('name') === 'fb:app_id';
        }).getAttribute('content');`

Answer (score 3):

Note: Some use the `property` attribute:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890">
```

whereas others use the `name` attribute:

```
 <meta name="fb:app_id" content="1234567890">
```

I use the following to get the value from both variants:

```
var appId = (function(c) { for (var a = document.getElementsByTagName("meta"), b = 0;b < a.length;b++) {
  if (c == a[b].name || c == a[b].getAttribute("property")) { return a[b].content; } } return false;
})("fb:app_id");

console.log(appId); //(bool)false if meta tag "fb:app_id" not exists.
```

---

The same can be used for every other meta tag as well - just change the input value on the closure function (eg. from `fb:app_id` to `description`).

---

**Edit:** Or as a more generic function:

```
function getContentByMetaTagName(c) {
  for (var b = document.getElementsByTagName("meta"), a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
    if (c == b[a].name || c == b[a].getAttribute("property")) { return b[a].content; }
  } return false;
}

console.log(getContentByMetaTagName("og:title"));
```