# Dynamically changing the content of: meta property="og:image"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-opengraph

I want to change  the main photo in a web page, I just have the url page. So I decided to use the meta written for Facebook sharing.

I want to change the image in: **meta property="og:image"** content="http://myweb.com/image.jpg"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it with jQuery like:

```
$('meta[property=og\\:image]').attr('content', 'http://myweb.com/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change `og:image` with following code:

```
$('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', newVideoUrl);
```

**But,** if you want to change the image permanently (so Facebook can scrape your data and the image will be available for sharing), you need to change this value on the server.

**Facebook is reading `<meta og:image>` only from the response of the server.**

See similar topic: [Facebook scraper doesn't load dynamic meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898673/facebook-scraper-doesnt-load-dynamic-meta-tags)

Answer (score 1):

for javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('meta[property=og\\:image]')[0].setAttribute('content', 'http://myweb.com/image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451559/get-meta-attribute-content-by-selecting-property-attribute) can be useful to you. Instead of getAttribute you should use setAttribute and thats all. :-)